# UITableView in popoverviewController

Tags: ipad, xcode4.5, uipopovercontroller

I m developing an ipad application and I need a UItableView in popoverviewController.I m struggling a lot for this since two days.I m getting popoverviewController but unable to get UItableView inside it .And also I could see a lot of shadow around popover,and I could dismiss popover on a single click any where on the screen.

```
-(IBAction)btnClick
{
if([array count]!=0)
{
  UIViewController* popoverviewContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController
            if(autocompleteTableView)
                [autocompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];

            autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,270,250) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
            autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
            autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];

            autocompleteTableView.backgroundView = nil;
            autocompleteTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            autocompleteTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            [autocompleteTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];


          popoverviewContent.view = autocompleteTableView;
                    UIPopoverController    *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverviewContent];
            popoverController.delegate=self;
            [popoverviewContent release];

            [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];


            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(410, 120,270, 250)inView:testscroll permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];


            [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
            for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
            {
                NSString *curString = [[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"FName"];
                [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];

            }


        }
        [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];

```
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController: tableViewController];
    [popover setDelegate:self];

    self.popoverViewController = popover;

    CGRect buttonFrame = [someButton frame];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 260)];

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect: buttonFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Check this implementation for displaying a tableview in a popover.

PS: Mention the required implementation to check your issues better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is not so optimised . So let me optimise it. It will solve your problem.

```
if(!popoverviewController)
    {
        //Always best is to implement TableviewController than creating tableview and adding it to UIViewController
        tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];

        //Should set contentsize of the presenting viewcontroller before adding to popovercontroller
        [tableViewController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];

        Assign yout Tableview propertis here
        //Set the TableViewCOntroller object and PopOvercontroller object globally.
        popoverviewController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController: tableViewController];

        //Assign some properties of popover Controller here

    }
//This will always execute so you should dat actions and present the viewController
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        NSString *curString = [[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"FName"];
        [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];

    }
[autocompleteTableView reloadData];
[popoverviewController presentPopoverFromRect: buttonFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Note:

Dont remove your view and add

Always Reuse views for PopoverControllers

If you dont use ARC release the objects whenever necessary otherwise dont

Comment: I got this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setPopoverContentSize:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.What shall I do ?